# Exchange limit and integral sign in front of Heat kernel

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have encountered a problem regarding the exchange of limit and integral sign. Currently,I am doing a problem which relates to the heat kernel. Suppose $u(t,x)$ is the solution of heat equation and $u(0,x) = f(x)$ which is bounded and continuous. Therefore, we can express the solution by Heat Kernel:

\begin{equation}
u(t,x) = \frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}} f(y) dy
\end{equation}

Then, I need to prove both equalities:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} u(t,x) = 0, \quad \quad \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}(4 \pi t)^{n/2} u(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(y) dy
\end{equation}

My idea is that by using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem,  we can switch the order of limit and integral sign and I can prove these two equalities. Suppose I am dealing with second equality, I need to construct a sequence $\{ t_{n} \}$ such that it converges to $t = \infty$. Besides, I need to construct a sequence of function $\{ h_{n} \}$
\begin{equation}
h_{n}  = e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t_{n}}} f(y)
\end{equation} 
In order to apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, we need to prove $h_{n} \rightarrow h$ pointwisely and $ |h_{n} | \leq g$ where $g$ is a integrable function. My difficulties are that that I do not know how to construct the  a sequence $\{ t_{n} \}$ which
 converges to $t = \infty$ and $h_{n} \rightarrow h$ pointwisely.

Comment: $f$ bounded and continuous doesn't seem enough. Should we add $f\in L^1?$

Comment: Yes,  I think it should be $f \in L^{1}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the second limit implies the first limit. To obtain the second limit, note that

$$(4 \pi t)^{n/2}u(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}} f(y) dy.$$

Let $y=x+z.$ Then the integral on the right equals

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{\frac{-|z|}{4t}} f(x+z) \,dz.$$

Think of the integrands here as $f_t(z).$ We then have $f_t(z)\to f(x+z)$ pointwise everywhere. We also have  $|f_t(z)|\le |f(x+z)|$ for all $t,z,$ and $f(x+z)\in L^1.$ By the DCT,

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f_t(z)\,dz \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x+z) \,dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(y) \,dy.$$